# Is that possible if I have the same items with different prices and only display those with the lowest values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have duplicate entries from my query with different prices. Now I only want to have the lowest price displayed so that the double is no longer displayed. Is that possible? Shown here as a picture as I mean it. I hope you can help me.

My query in MSSQL

```
SELECT m.artikel, z.plan_auftrag,b.auftrag_nr, b.price, b.erranf_dat, s.a_status
FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_zusatz] z
JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[auftrags_bestand] b
ON z.auftrag_nr = b.aunr
JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrag_status] s
ON b.auftrag_nr = s.auftrag_nr
JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[mlst_hy] m
ON s.auftrag_nr = m.auftrag_nr  
AND s.a_status IN ('V','L')
AND m.kennz = 'M'
AND s.eingeplant = ('M')
AND b.masch_nr='QTA3'   
ORDER BY s.a_status ASC, b.erranf_dat ASC, b.price ASC
```

now:

[image]

What i want:

[image]

The answer from Isaac was the solution (Thank you). Now I have one more question. I would like now that the duplication if a_status = L is not deleted. Has anyone a piece of information for me?

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried using `min()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the lowest priced row for each article.

```
SELECT   *
FROM     (
             SELECT
                  m.artikel
                , z.plan_auftrag
                , b.auftrag_nr
                , b.price
                , b.erranf_dat
                , s.a_status
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.artikel ORDER BY b.price) AS [row_number]
             FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_zusatz] z
             JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[auftrags_bestand]  b ON z.auftrag_nr = b.aunr
             JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrag_status]  s ON b.auftrag_nr = s.auftrag_nr
             JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[mlst_hy]           m ON s.auftrag_nr = m.auftrag_nr
                                                         AND s.a_status IN ('V', 'L')
                                                         AND m.kennz      = 'M'
                                                         AND s.eingeplant = ('M')
                                                         AND b.masch_nr   = 'QTA3'
         ) AS x
WHERE    x.row_number = 1
ORDER BY x.a_status ASC
       , x.erranf_dat ASC
       , x.price ASC;
```